# Rails delete multiple objects checkboxes with fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models - Campaigns & Cities (belongs to Campaign). On the create and edit form for Campaign I'm using fields_for to allow users to edit cities directly on the campaign edit page. I want to add a checkbox for each city, so that their ids will be sent in an array (delete_cities) in the params.

My attempt at it:

```
<%= f.fields_for :cities do | city_form | %>
      <%= city_form.label :name %>
      <%= city_form.text_field :name%>
      <%= city_form.label :phone_number %>
      <%= city_form.text_field :phone_number %>
      <%= city_form.label :zip_code %>
      <%= city_form.text_field :zip_code %>
      <%= city_form.check_box :delete_cities %>
      </br>
    <% end %>
```

I cant solve this any help is appeciated.

Comment: try using `check_box_tag 'delete_cities[]'`

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

> :allow_destroy
>
> If true, destroys any members from the attributes hash with a _destroy key and a value that evaluates to true (eg. 1, '1', true, or 'true'). This option is off by default.

In order to allow users to delete cities, you can do like this:

```
<%= city_form.check_box :_destroy %>
```

And don't forget to permit `:_destroy` in the controller:

```
params.require(:campaign).permit(cities_attributes: [:id, :_destroy])
```